# Savings and investment relation to interest rate, loanable funds theory, paradox of thrift

Tags: investment, saving

HOw can it all be linked? I think I know but I am only a fresher so.

Answer (score 1):

Investment is inversely proportional to the interest rate and savings is proportional to the interest rate, but if the quantity of savings increases, investment also increases according to the equation $I = S + T-G+M-X$. You can illustrate this by graphing the demand and supply of loanable funds on a 2-D plane (savings affects the supply of loanable funds), which shows how the two curves determine the real interest rate.

Comment: Thanks. If you see savings and inv graph is a purely classical case. So how do I move on to prove the Paradox of Thrift.

Comment: I don't know what the paradox of thrift is.